# Maximization of convex quadratic function for diagonal matrices over Euclidean ball

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

Let's say $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^d$. I am trying to solve the following optimization problems:

\begin{equation}
\underset{\|\epsilon\| _{\infty} \le \rho}{\operatorname{arg max}} \ \epsilon^T b + \epsilon^T D \epsilon 
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\underset{\|\epsilon\| _{2} \le \rho}{\operatorname{arg max}} \ \epsilon^T b + \epsilon^T D \epsilon 
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

where $D$ is a diagonal positive semidefinite $d \times d$ matrix.

I know for the minimization case when $D$ is not diagonal this problem is known as the trust-region subproblem and does not have a closed-form solution. I wondered if there is a closed-form solution for at least one of the above problems.

Comment: Are they really maximization (and not minimization) problems? Maximizing a convex quadratic is a hard problem.

Comment: At least we know that the only critical point to the problem within the region is a local minimum, so we can guarantee that any maximum must occur on the region's boundary

Comment: Yes. the problem is Maximization. I know without the second term (the term that contains D) it becomes a dual norm problem and there is a closed-form solution for it which happens on the boundary of constraint. I feel for these problems also the optimal solution is on the boundary.

Comment: I agree with you @BenGrossmann

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that problem (2) admits a closed form solution.

As I note in my comment, we know that the only critical point to the problem that is potentially in the interior of the region is a local minimum, so we can guarantee that any maximum must occur on the region's boundary. Denote $f(\epsilon) = \epsilon^Tb + \epsilon^TD\epsilon$, $g(\epsilon) = \|\epsilon\|_2^2 = \epsilon^T\epsilon$.

With Lagrange multipliers, the optimum occurs where $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$. We compute
$$
\nabla f = b + 2D\epsilon, \quad \nabla g = 2\epsilon.
$$
From there,
$$
b + 2D\epsilon = 2\lambda \epsilon \implies\\
2(\lambda I - D)\epsilon  = b \implies\\
\epsilon = \frac 12 (\lambda I - D)^{-1}b.
$$
Applying the constraint $g(\epsilon) = \rho^2$, we have
$$
\frac 14 b^T(\lambda I - D)^{-2}b = \rho^2 \implies
\sum_{i=1}^d \frac{b_i^2}{(\lambda - d_i)^2} = 4 \rho^2,
$$
but I'm not sure where to proceed from here. At the very least, we have reduced the problem to one of finding the roots of a polynomial.

Comment: Seems there is no closed-form solution for $\lambda$ in this case.

Comment: @Arman In retrospect I think you’re right

Comment: I am thinking of using a projected gradient ascent to solve this. Projection on the sphere has a closed-form solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "projection on the sphere" here?

Comment: I mean in each step we calculate the gradient and the find the closest vector to the updated vector on the euclidean ball and repeating this multiple steps. Basically projected gradient ascent algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

**The first optimization problem has a closed-form solution.**

The problem can be written as
$$
{\max \sum_{i=1}^n d_{ii}\epsilon_i^2+b_i\epsilon_i
\\
\text{s. t.}
\\|\epsilon_i|\le \rho\quad,\quad 1\le i\le n.
}
$$
The state of the problem allows us to optimize each of the $\epsilon_i$s, regardless of the others, i.e., an equivalent form of the problem is solving
$$
{\max d_{ii}\epsilon_i^2+b_i\epsilon_i
\\
\text{s. t.}
\\-\rho\le \epsilon_i\le \rho
}
$$
for each $i$ and gather the results altogether. The optimal point for the latter problem is
$$
\epsilon_i^*=\text{sign}(b_i)\cdot\rho,
$$
where $\text{sign}$ denotes the sign function and we assumed $\text{sign}(0)=1$. Therefore, the optimal argument to the original problem is
$$
\epsilon^*=\rho\cdot \begin{bmatrix}\text{sign}(b_1)&\text{sign}(b_2)&\cdots&\text{sign}(b_n)\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: How come D doesn't have any role in the solution?